# Flink solution to active - active Multi site cloud data ingestion

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have Flink job consuming data from Kafka and ingest it to multi-site replicated Cassandra.

Now we have to aggregate data hourly.
The problem is that device X can report once on site A and once on site B. This means that some messages for that device, will be processed by Flink in site A and some messages will be processed on site B.

I want an aggregation result that will reflect all messages transmitted by specific device X.

Are there any best practices to handle multi site ingestion? any idea how to handle the scenario above?
Thanks in advance.